# Port restriction when using NetTcpBinding with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I know that Silverlight has a port limitation when using nettcpbinding. What I don't know and don't have time to test is, if the ports 4502-4534 is opened on the server, this restriction still applies to clients behind a corporate firewall which only lets the users inside the corporate network to use only ports 80/8080, right?

So opening the port 4502 on the server is not enough, all the clients must be behind a firewall that lets them to connect to port 4502 on my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have an uncommon situation, your corporate firewall should allow -outbound- connections to any port, but only allow -inbound- connections on 80/8080.  Is that correct?  If that is the case, you shouldn't have a problem if only your client is behind the firewall.

The firewall that the server is behind needs to allow incoming connections on ports 4502-4534 to your server.